# Whats the issue with my code for Linked List reversal Recursive Method?

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to reverse linked list using recursion.When I display the list after reversing I only get the first element of the original list
 `

```
        void reve(node *a,node *b,node *c,node *h1)
       {
               if(c->next==NULL)
           {
               c->next=b;
               b->next=a;
                return ;
           }

           reve(a->next,b->next,c->next,h1);
           c->next=b;
           b->next=a;
           if(a==h1)
         {
            a->next=NULL;
         }

         return ;

      }`
```

Comment: Did you debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your calling code still holds a pointer to the node that used to be first, but that node is last now.
(At least if the code actually works – it's difficult to keep track of all those parameters, and their relationship is as mysterious as their names.)

This is easier to implement if you return a pointer to the new head.
You also only need one (1) parameter.

Then you have three cases to handle:

1. The empty list – just return the empty list;
2. A singleton list – just return it;
3. The general case.

You can solve the general case by first reversing the rest of the list, receiving the new head.

Then you need to make `next` of the "new last element" point to "this" node in order to make "this" node the next element of the reversed list.
This is easier than it sounds – the last node in the reversed list you got from the recursion is still this node's `next` node.
(Draw it on paper if it's unclear.)

Then you also need to make "this" node terminate the list by nulling its `next`.

Then return the "new head" you received from the recursion.

```
node* reverse(node* n)
{
    // Empty list:
    if (!n)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    // Singleton list:
    if (!n->next)
    {
        return n;
    }
    // General case:
    node* head = reverse(n->next); // Reverse the rest,
    n->next->next = n;             // Attach this node at the end,
    n->next = nullptr;             // Terminate the list,
    return head;                   // Done.
}
```

Comment: You *can* condense the first two cases to `if (!n || !n->next) { return n; }`, but  I'm not sure that's better

Comment: I wanted to keep the "three cases" structure in the code (a habit I picked up using languages with pattern matching). It's easier to reason about each case separately and convince yourself that it's correct.